# If $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and $g(x)=(x-4)(x-5)$ are congruent, find $a-b-c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I got this question on my homework.  please help me solve this problem with 8th grade Algebra.

Comment: What do you mean by "congruent polynomials"? Congruent respect to which relation?

Comment: If you mean identical or equal (as functions) then expand $g(x)$ and equate the coefficients one by one.

Answer (score 1):

If the two functions are congruent, does that mean they are identical functions?

If so, then simply foil $g(x)$ to find $x^2-9x+20$. Since this is now in the form of $f(x)$, you should be able to solve by simply observing the values for $a,b,c$ and then calculating $a-b-c$.